# How to make better ? (use xml type in database or create this strucute in database on my own)

Tags: xml, database, dynamic-data, heterogeneous

Now I am creating small web services and I want to know how to make them better and more productive.
I need to keep dynamical data and I have two ways how to do it.

I need to keep data in similar xml structure
Like this:
[image]

Or I need to use standart xml type in MS SQL SERVER Like this:

[image]

where Data:xml

The small web services will be used for getting information about text corpus files and their annottations.

The data which I want to keep in this dynamic structure:

```
<author>
 <name>Bob</name>
 <surname>Simpson</surname>
 <sex>male</sex>
</author>
```

and other data which can be created dynamically.

I need to use this dynamical structure, because of all attribute fields can be used in the future for dynamically searching.

The database will keep about 60.000 annotations.

But I don not know which of these ways is better.
Can you help me chose one of them and describe why do you chose this or that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is used xml in practice. It's more difficult but it's more productive than the first way.